# How do you pass arguments with UnityEvents?

Tags: unity

I was inspired by a great talk at Unite by Ryan Hipple.

https://youtu.be/raQ3iHhE_Kk?t=28m

His examples didn’t cover passing arguments with UnityEvents

Do I need to extend UnityEvent, GameEvent and GameEventListener from a generic base class for this to work properly?

If so do I need to make a new set of classes for each Type and combination of Types that I want to pass?

Game Event Scriptable Object

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
    public class GameEvent : ScriptableObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The list of listeners that this event will notify if it is raised.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly List<GameEventListener> eventListeners = 
            new List<GameEventListener>();

        public void Raise()
        {
            for(int i = eventListeners.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
                eventListeners[i].OnEventRaised();
        }

        public void RegisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
        {
            if (!eventListeners.Contains(listener))
                eventListeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public void UnregisterListener(GameEventListener listener)
        {
            if (eventListeners.Contains(listener))
                eventListeners.Remove(listener);
        }
    }
```

Listener Class

```
public class GameEventListener : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Tooltip("Event to register with.")]
        public GameEvent Event;

        [Tooltip("Response to invoke when Event is raised.")]
        public UnityEvent Response;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Event.RegisterListener(this);
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            Event.UnregisterListener(this);
        }

        public void OnEventRaised()
        {
            Response.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to create a sub-class of the `UnityEvent` class as follow:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GameObjectEvent : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent<GameObject> {} // Leave it empty
```

And then:

```
public class GameEventListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Event to register with.")]
    public GameEvent Event;

    [Tooltip("Response to invoke when Event is raised.")]
    public GameObjectEvent Response;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Event.RegisterListener(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Event.UnregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void OnEventRaised()
    {
        Response.Invoke( gameObject );
    }
}
```

I have never found an alternative to create a new class for every type, except using `System.Action<your_type>`, but you won't be able to use the Inspector anymore to call the function you want (unless you have a plugin to serialize the System.Action)

Comment: Can you pass in custom classes or only game objects and primitives ?

Comment: You can pass the type you want :)

Comment: Fortunately you no longer need to create your own custom type. As of 2020, the Unity serializer now handles this type of generic natively, so `UnityEvent<GameObject>` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment but this is expanding on what Hellium said)
Worth noting that you will need to adjust the Raised and OnEventRaised methods accordingly as well:

```
public void OnEventRaised(GameObject gameObject)
{
    Response.Invoke( gameObject );
}
```

Like this in the inspector it will show up to select a dynamic gameObject, which is the one that will be passed on from wherever you're going to be invoking the event:

`EventName?.Invoke(gameObject);`

For me this was useful for this case:
`DamageTakenEvent?.Invoke(collision.gameObject);`